# 2x2 grid images with space of equal width with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, xetex

Relating to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473741/pictures-on-horizontal-page-in-a-2x2-grid-with-equal-distances-between-them-and) question on tex stackexchange, I would like to implement the below code in `tikz`.

I am particularly keen to have each white space equally wide. By writing white spaces I mean the margins, the distance of the images to the page border (left or right, top or bottom) as well as the spaces between the images all with the same width.

Is this even possible if the aspect ratio of the images vary ("not too much")?

This is my MWE without `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0cm, top=0cm, bottom=0cm, outer=0cm, inner=0cm, landscape, a4paper]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
  \centering\hfill
 \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-a}\label{figure1}}\hspace{1cm}
 \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-b}\label{figure2}}\hfill\null\\
 \hfill
 \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-c}\label{figure3}}\hspace{1cm}
 \subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image}\label{figure4}}\hfill\null
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have fun ;) Life is easier with `positioning`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) (a) {\includegraphics[height=6cm]{example-image-a}};
    \node[below = 5cm of a.south west,anchor= west] (b) {\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-b}};
    \node[right = 2cm of a, anchor = west] (c) {\includegraphics[height=7cm]{example-image-c}};
    \node[below = 5cm of c.south east,anchor= east] (d) {\includegraphics[height=6cm]{example-image}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

you will get:

[image]

Comment: @Til Hund Advantage `TikZ` ;) Have fun `Tikzing!`.

Comment: Awesome, Raaja!

Comment: @Til Hund Welcome!